# log4j:ERROR Error sending logging event to Log Analytics

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j, azure-databricks, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to send azure databricks logs to azure log analytics workspace using the steps given in [github Documentation](https://github.com/mspnp/spark-monitoring/blob/master/README.md). The code i am using in databricks notebook is

```
import com.microsoft.pnp.util.TryWith
import com.microsoft.pnp.logging.Log4jConfiguration
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.slf4j.Logger


val loggerName :String = "fromNotebook"
val level : String = "INFO" 
val logType: String = "HerculesDataBricksUAT"

val log4jConfig = s"""
log4j.appender.logAnalytics=com.microsoft.pnp.logging.loganalytics.LogAnalyticsAppender
log4j.appender.logAnalytics.layout=com.microsoft.pnp.logging.JSONLayout
log4j.appender.logAnalytics.layout.LocationInfo=false
log4j.appender.logAnalytics.logType=$logType
log4j.additivity.$loggerName=false
log4j.logger.$loggerName=$level, logAnalytics
"""
TryWith(new ByteArrayInputStream(log4jConfig.getBytes())) {
  stream => {
    Log4jConfiguration.configure(stream)


    }
    }
val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerName);
logger.info("logging info from " + loggerName)
 logger.warn("Warn message  " + loggerName)
logger.error("Error message  " + loggerName)
```

My

> /home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/dbconf/log4j/executor/log4j.properties
>   for this appender looks like

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console, logAnalyticsAppender
# logAnalytics
log4j.appender.logAnalyticsAppender=com.microsoft.pnp.logging.loganalytics.LogAnalyticsAppender
log4j.appender.logAnalyticsAppender.filter.spark=com.microsoft.pnp.logging.SparkPropertyEnricher
#Disable all other logs
log4j.appender.logAnalyticsAppender.Threshold=INFO
```

But it is showing weird behavior to me. It will work fine for level *INFO* but if I try to log anything below or above the level I declared in configuration it will throw below error. and after that no matter what changes I make in my code, it will only work after I restart my cluster. My cluster Performance is also getting impacted once it throw the error. Sometime This code even keep on running for indefinite period of time.

Error I am getting is:

```
> log4j:ERROR Error sending logging event to Log Analytics
> java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
> com.microsoft.pnp.client.loganalytics.LogAnalyticsSendBufferTask@5b2a430
> rejected from
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@699636fd[Terminated, pool size
> = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 112]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
>   at
> com.microsoft.pnp.client.GenericSendBuffer.send(GenericSendBuffer.java:88)
>   at
> com.microsoft.pnp.client.loganalytics.LogAnalyticsSendBufferClient.sendMessage(LogAnalyticsSendBufferClient.java:43)
>   at
> com.microsoft.pnp.logging.loganalytics.LogAnalyticsAppender.append(LogAnalyticsAppender.java:52)
>   at
> org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
>   at
> org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
>   at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)   at
> org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)    at
> org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)  at
> org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.info(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:305)
>   at log4jWrapper.MyLogger.info(MyLogger.scala:48)    at
> line07d51ea7c1834afc957316967b0d0e8225.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-764707897465587:10)
>   at
> line07d51ea7c1834afc957316967b0d0e8225.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-764707897465587:63)
>   at
> line07d51ea7c1834afc957316967b0d0e8225.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-764707897465587:65)
>   at
> line07d51ea7c1834afc957316967b0d0e8225.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-764707897465587:67)
>   at
> line07d51ea7c1834afc957316967b0d0e8225.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-764707897465587:69)
>   at
> line07d51ea7c1834afc957316967b0d0e8225.$read$$iw.<init>(command-764707897465587:71)
>   at
> line07d51ea7c1834afc957316967b0d0e8225.$read.<init>(command-764707897465587:73)
>   at
> line07d51ea7c1834afc957316967b0d0e8225.$read$.<init>(command-764707897465587:77)
>   at
> line07d51ea7c1834afc957316967b0d0e8225.$read$.<clinit>(command-764707897465587)
>   at
> line07d51ea7c1834afc957316967b0d0e8225.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
>   at line07d51ea7c1834afc957316967b0d0e8225.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
>   at line07d51ea7c1834afc957316967b0d0e8225.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
>   at
> scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
>   at
> scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
>   at
> scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
>   at
> scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
>   at
> scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
>   at
> scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
>   at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)     at
> scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)  at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:685)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:638)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:373)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:350)
>   at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
>   at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)   at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:48)
>   at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:271)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:48)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:350)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
>   at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)     at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

i found out the solution. Actually in databricks notebook environment if you try to run following code more than once **for same logger name** it will throw above error since the configuration is global once it is set (which can only be removed after cluster restarts).

```
TryWith(new ByteArrayInputStream(log4jConfig.getBytes())) {
  stream => {
    Log4jConfiguration.configure(stream)
    }
    }
```

solution i found is

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager
if(LogManager.exists(loggerName) == null) {
    TryWith(new ByteArrayInputStream(log4jConfig.getBytes())) {
      stream => {
        Log4jConfiguration.configure(stream)
      }
    }
  }
```

it will prohibit configuring your logger again.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.